# How do I get a sprite's angle after collision?

Tags: sprites, rotation, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm using Cocos2d (version 3) and I want my hero sprite to be jostled around by incoming enemy sprites. The Chipmunk-based physics work, but I need some way to track the rotation of the sprite after a collision has ended. How do I do this? I tried `sprite.rotation`, etc.

Comment: I don't know Cocos2D, but don't you need to supply some angle value to even draw the sprite at that rotation?

Comment: No, you just add it to your layer.  You can rotate programmatically but when Chipmunk, the Physics package takes over it's not clear.  I think I need to use the textureRect before and after the collision but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I'm trying to build a wheelchair simulation game and I need to know the forward angle of the sprite to apply the proper forward impulse to move forward.

Comment: It always helps to let the application run before you return the angle --- LOL.